# How can I show the contents of only a few users

Tags: admin, options

I'm trying to show the contents only for certain registered users. All users have the role of "agent". To hide the contents of an unregistered user, I use this code:

```
<?php if  ( current_user_can( 'agent' )  ){ ?>
    ///here the content
<?php } ?>
```

Now I want to show the contents only for users with id 8,9, with this code:

```
<?php if  ( current_user_can( 'agent=8,9' )  ){ ?>
    ///here the content
<?php } ?>`,`<?php if  ( current_user_can( 'author_name=Jacks,David' )  ){ ?>
    ///here the contents
<?php } ?>
```

But nothing happens!!!
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

To show content only for users with role 'agent', try to use this snippet:

```
<?php if ( ( $user = wp_get_current_user() ) && in_array( 'agent', $user->roles ) ) { ?>
    ///here the content
<?php } ?>
```

If you want to block users by ID, check the following snippet:

```
<?php if ( ( $user = wp_get_current_user() ) && in_array( 'agent', $user->roles ) && in_array( $user->ID, array( 8, 9 ) ) ) { ?>
    ///here the content
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Where to send the id or the names of agents?

Comment: This code works for me, but I would like for some users:<?php if  ( current_user_can( 'agent' )  ){ ?>
    ///here the content
<?php } ?>

Comment: Function `current_user_can` checks only user capabilities, not roles. As an option you can add `agent` capability into `agent` role, and then this function will work.

Comment: Added for checking for users' IDs.

Comment: Eugene Thank you very much, worked like clockwork.